# Heroku process not starting after deploying it

Tags: heroku

I'm pretty new to Heroku and I tried three times to deploy my code on it without success. I'm following [this](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js) tutorial and I get stuck when it asks me to do `heroku ps:scale web=1` on which I receive `Scaling web processes...  !    Resource not found`. This sounds not really correct. All the previous steps seems working correctly. Here is the logs of the command `git push heroku master`:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 279 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.4.7
       Using npm version: 1.0.106
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
   npm WARN nodeunit@0.5.1 package.json: bugs['web'] should probably be bugs['url']

   > mongodb@0.9.7-3-5 install /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/mongodb
   > node install.js

   ================================================================================
   =                                                                              =
   =  To install with C++ bson parser do <npm install mongodb --mongodb:native>   =
   =                                                                              =
   ================================================================================
   mongodb@0.9.7-3-5 ./node_modules/mongodb 

   > mongodb@0.9.7-3-5 install /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/mongodb
   > node install.js

   ================================================================================
   =                                                                              =
   =  To install with C++ bson parser do <npm install mongodb --mongodb:native>   =
   =                                                                              =
   ================================================================================
   xmlhttprequest@1.3.0 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/xmlhttprequest
   redis@0.6.0 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/redis
   mongoose@2.5.5 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/mongoose
   mongodb@0.9.7-3-5 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/mongodb
   juggernaut@2.0.5 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/juggernaut
   socket.io@0.6.18 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/juggernaut/node_modules/socket.io
   redis@0.5.11 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/juggernaut/node_modules/redis
   node-static-maccman@0.5.3 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/juggernaut/node_modules/node-static-maccman
   optimist@0.1.9 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/juggernaut/node_modules/optimist
   jquery@1.6.3 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/jquery
   jsdom@0.2.13 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom
   htmlparser@1.7.4 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/htmlparser
   jade@0.20.1 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/jade
   html2jade@0.1.16 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/html2jade
   express@2.3.4 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/express
   connect@1.4.1 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect
   qs@0.1.0 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/express/node_modules/qs
   mime@1.2.2 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/express/node_modules/mime
   ejs@0.4.2 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/ejs
   connect@1.8.5 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/connect
   qs@0.4.1 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/connect/node_modules/qs
   mime@1.2.4 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/connect/node_modules/mime
   formidable@1.0.8 /tmp/build_2xv21ycwhho11/node_modules/connect/node_modules/formidable
   Dependencies installed
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compiled slug size is 7.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v4
       http://stark-winter-4562.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:stark-winter-4562.git
   43e3a5e..84f9cd8  master -> master
```

I don't know if this can be of any help, but I guess this output is pretty different from the one seen in the tutorial, just in case.

Can anyone point out what's wrong, or what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify that you have created a procfile? If we can see your code/project it may be more helpful

Comment: I created it, it's in the same folder as the node server. It's just a file called `procfile` with no extension and it's composed by a single line: `web: node server.js`.

Comment: Ok, I tried all the steps once again, but I deleted the `.git` folder this time and did it again. Now it seems to work, but the app seems to be crashed. Any idea how to start it up again? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your procfile needs to be called `Procfile` with a capitalised P